# SD hard drive: does it exist?

Tags: hard-drive, sd-card

I'm looking for a portable hard drive enclosure (2.5" notebook) that plugs into an SD card slot and LOOKS like an SD card to the camera.  The obvious advantage being unlimited space for video recording.

But where it really comes in handy (and crucial) is when you factor in how long it takes to transfer a giant multi-GB video file from the camera's SD card to a hard drive.  As far as I can tell, the fastest possible setup maxes at about 20MB/s.

(Similar to how Eye-Fi works)

Answer (score 4):

Well, no, I don't think (and a quick google search confirms) that such devices exist. Then again, SD standards limit the amount of storage space available. Even the "top" SDHC (Secure Digital High Capacity also SD 2.0) standard at the moment is limited to 32 GB max. So there will be no unlimited storage space for you there.

The SDXC (Secure Digital Extended Capacity) standard is announced, but not widely implemented yet. SDXC has a theoretical limit of 2TB.

Answer (score 0):

There's really nothing like this. There are SD cards with a built in USB connector on the back that can be plugged in for transfers, but not what you're looking for. Some professional cameras (Canon 5D?) can be tethered to a computer for shooting, but not much knowledge there. In the consumer world I think we're stuck with SD cards and USB 2.0 transfer speeds.

Comment: Pretty much all SLRs can be shot tethered.

Comment: @FakeName - Ummm..no.  Even the new'ish Nikon D3100 can't officially, and all third party apps I've tried have it at least various, large bug (like, maybe it can't do exposure compensation or change the aperture, or such).

Comment: Ok, let me correct myself. All *Canon* SLRs at least can shoot tethered.